# Android Intent Call

Tags: android, android-intent

I have two activities:

1. MainActivity
2. Play

In MainActivity - there is a ImageButton - on clicking of which Intent will call Play activity.
But after calling startActivity(i) - My programe stopes.

### Please please help
My manifest file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.multiplication">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="Multiplication"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Multiplication">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Play"> </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

### =====================================
And the MainActivity is:

```
package com.example.multiplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        ImageButton btnMathPlay = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.play);
        ImageButton btnMathShare= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.share);
        ImageButton btnMathRate = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.grade);

        btnMathPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //
                //  Example of Explicit Intent
                //  When you click Play Button on the screen
                //  Game Activity will be started
                //
                //Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Play.class);
                Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this, Play.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
  }

    }
```

### The error is:

```
 public void run() {
            try {
                mMethod.invoke(null, new Object[] { mArgs });
            } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            } catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {
                Throwable cause = ex.getCause();
                if (cause instanceof RuntimeException) {
                    throw (RuntimeException) cause;
                } else if (cause instanceof Error) {
                    throw (Error) cause;
                }
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
```

Just stops program

Comment: Please share the stacktrace

Comment: Hi Sanjib, thanks for your question. If it's stop the program, then you have to see the LogCat in your Android Studio. It contains information of the cause of your stopped program

Comment: Hello, Could you add the code of Play( Maybe it should be ' PlayActivity') and the code from de logcat.

Comment: Many thanks.

With the log  I have solved my issue.

The main issue was:

<activity android:name=".Play"> </activity>

When I rebuild the project - it worked fine.

Many thanks for all the supports